# How to publish adobe edge animation to custom wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

Can anyone explain to me how I can publish an edge animation to a custom wordpress plugin. I've set the target directory and the images, and js folder relative to that, but when i run the page, its looking for a javascript relative to that wordpress page, where im using a custom short code.

Here is the files that are published

```
/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/edge_includes/edge.5.0.1.min.js
/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/eye_piece_edge.js
/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/eye_piece.html
```

I point to edge.5.0.1.min.js the following in plugin script

```
function myplugin_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'quiz-edge',
        plugins_url('/edge_includes/edge.5.0.1.min.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery')
    );
wp_enqueue_script(
        'quiz-edge-dddd',
        plugins_url('eye_piece_edge.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery')
    );
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'quiz-init',
        plugins_url('/js/init.js', __FILE__ ),
        array('jquery')
    );
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myplugin_scripts');


/* init.js */

AdobeEdge.loadComposition('eye_piece', 'EDGE-52583590', {
    scaleToFit: "none",
    centerStage: "none",
    minW: "0",
    maxW: "undefined",
    width: "460px",
    height: "320px"
}, {dom: [ ]}, {dom: [ ]});
```

Im using short code to display markup on page mywordpress.com/mypage/

```
function mypluginIndex( $atts, $content = "" ) {

    global $wpdb;

    $html = '<form name="quiz-form" action="/quiz/" method="post">';

    $html .= '<ul class="quiz-list">';
    $html .= '
        <li>
            <p>Statement 1</p>
            <p><div id="Stage" class="EDGE-52583590"></div></p>
            <p>
                <input type="radio" name="question_one_choice" value="1">
                <input type="radio" name="question_one_choice" value="2">
                <input type="radio" name="question_one_choice" value="3">
                <input type="radio" name="question_one_choice" value="4">
            </p>
        </li>';

    return $html;

}
add_shortcode('myPuginShortCode', 'mypluginIndex');
```

I'm getting a 404 - mywordpress.com/mypage/eye_piece_edge.js

I'm assuming the eye_piece_edge.js is dynamically loaded when its defined here, AdobeEdge.loadComposition('eye_piece', 'EDGE-57338104', {
but how can I override that, and use wp_enqueue_script

Im not getting any other errors, other than that 404, and the wp_enqueue is loading eye_piece_edge.js, but animation is not running.

**Update:**

I made an error on file names above. Edited to show eye_piece_edge.js rather than glasses_edge.js

Comment: you have same handle(`quiz-edge`) for both `edge.5.0.1.min.js` and `eye_piece_edge.js` while enqueuing so you are getting 4044 error for that file..WP ignores the second file if they have same handle

Comment: I just caught that. Doesnt fix it. Thanks though.